# How to display last published post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a task to modify the code in one website so that it shows the latest post on the top of the page. The rest of the page is blog posts and this part of the code is fine. I'm just starting to learn PHP and have no clue what I need to do.

Here is the website so you can have a better understanding of what I need - https://yourbestbrace.staging.wpengine.com/
The post that is currently on top is not the last one published.

Also, the piece of the code that needs to be changed is placed in the header.php. Here it is ( full code screenshot since it wouldn't display the code properly, image part is missing - https://prnt.sc/oy6r8q):

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_key' => 'show_as_first',
        'meta_value' => 1
    )); 
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="new-home-title">Products Reviews of the Best Braces & Supports for You</h1>
    <div class="header-post">
        <div class="h-post-detail">
            <p class="sub-title-home">Featured Review</p>
            <h2> <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 22 ); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" class="read-more"> Read More</a>
        </div>


<?php endif;
```

Comment: Using this `'meta_key' => 'show_as_first',` suggests you are using a custom field to set to a post to be shown first. This is this one that will be queried. Try to remove the `meta_key` and `meta_value` conditions, it should show the latest post (it's the default without special conditions added to the query)

Comment: You are correct it did the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help!